# Cloud Datastore Client Library vs App Engine SDK on App Engine Go Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

When writing a Go App Engine Standard app, it used to be the case that you had to use the [App Engine SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/) to access the data store. However, these days (since Go 1.11?), it seems to work if you just use the [Cloud Datastore Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries).

Is there a downside of using the Cloud Datastore Client Library on App Engine Standard for accessing the datastore? (apart from a bit of extra configuration to make the dev appserver use the emulator). The advantage is that it enables code reuse for other environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine Standard for Go1.11 runs on the new, second generation (beta) runtime which doesn't have the limitations of the 1st generation and is capable of running any framework, library, or binary. On the other hand, App Engine no longer modifies the Go toolchain to include the `appengine` package and it is strongly recommended to use the Google Cloud client library or third party libraries instead of the App Engine-specific APIs.

For more details about this, I recommend to have a look at the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences) about the differences between both generations and how to handle them.